# Disable autoscroll for only certain anchor tags on a page

Tags: angularjs, anchor, autoscroll, angularjs-ng-include, angular-services

I have created an AngularJS service that dynamically inserts a div into the DOM with content from a template and a custom controller that handles the bindings and directives within the template.  The service, called `myService`, allows you to pass in the `templateUrl` and the `controllerName` as options.  Below is simplified code:

```
function display(id, templateUrl, controllerName) {
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.id = id;
  var element = angular.element('<div ng-include="\'' + templateUrl + '\'"></div>');
  var controller = $controller(controllerName, {$scope: scope});
  element.contents().data('$ngControllerController', controller);
  $compile(element)(scope);
  parentElement.append(elem);
}
```

I have a separate controller on the DOM that handles the `ng-click` on several anchor tags:

```
<a ng-click="handleClick(record.id, record.templateUrl, record.controllerName)">Click Me</a>
```

I'm not using a `$routeProvider` and there is no href and no id attributes on the anchor tags.  The click function invokes my custom service to render the div:

```
$scope.handleClick = function($event, id, templateUrl, controllerName) {
  myService.display(id, templateUrl, controllerName);
};
```

After the page loads in the Chrome browser and I scroll down so that a link with the `ng-click` is visible and then click the link, the browser scrolls to the top of the page.  I DO NOT want the page to scroll, just display the div next to the link.  Nothing changes in the URL in the location.  If I scroll back down, I see the new div displayed.  If I click a different link with the `ng-click`, then no scrolling takes place (which is what I wanted for the first click as well).  If I refresh the page, it doesn't matter which link I click first and the first click always causes the browser to scroll back to the top of the viewport.

If I don't put the `ng-include` directive in my new element and just hard-code the HTML of the template in the service instead, the scroll to the top of the page on the first click DOES NOT happen.

The [ngInclude documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) says that you can specify an optional `autoscroll` attribute and it says that if the attribute is not set, then it will "disable autoscroll".  It appears that this is not the case.  I tried setting autoscroll to "false", but that didn't help.

I know that I can do `$anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling()` to disable all autoscrolling, but what can I do to disable autoscroll for specific tags?  Is this a bug in Angular that I should report?  If so, is there are work-around I can use until that bug is fixed?

**EDIT**:  Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2NhkmU) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue using Angular v1.2.2, having an ng-include in a template file that was not loaded into the page from the start. When the template file was compiled $anchorScroll got initialized for the first time and for some reason reset the scroll.

My solution:

```
var example = angular.module('example', [])
    //Force initialization of $anchorScroll, so that the scroll doesn't reset when compiling an ngInclude that has been lazy loaded.
    .run(['$anchorScroll', function () { }]);
```

That way $anchorScroll initializes on page load and does nothing when the ng-include statement compiles in the lazy loaded template.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Philip Holly's comment](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll#comment-965706396) there was a change with version 1.1.5 where if there is no hash $anchorScroll causes the page to scroll to the top. The fix is adding:

```
angular.module('myApp').value('$anchorScroll', angular.noop);
```

Though I would think setting the `autoscroll` attribute as you did should have worked. Perhaps that is a bug.

Alternatively it looks like doing:

```
$location.hash("!");
```

just before the $compile also works.

Comment: I encounter the same problem with version 1.1.4.  Wouldn't setting $anchorScroll to a noop disable autoscroll for all anchors on the app, just like $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling()?